# Autoremove does not remove old headers

Tags: apt, kernel

I have a 16.04 installation with a weird problem

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

removes old kernels except the current and a previous, but does not remove old headers.

On other 16.04 installations it removes both.

How can I find out what is wrong?

I've spent a lot of time on learning how kernel autoremove works, but did not find any differences between working and non-working machines.

```
pilot6@Pilot6:~$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels
// DO NOT EDIT! File autogenerated by /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal
APT::NeverAutoRemove
{
   "^linux-image-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^linux-image-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^linux-image-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^linux-headers-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^linux-headers-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^linux-headers-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^linux-image-extra-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^linux-image-extra-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^linux-image-extra-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^linux-signed-image-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^linux-signed-image-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^linux-signed-image-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-image-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-image-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-image-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-headers-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-headers-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^kfreebsd-headers-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^gnumach-image-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^gnumach-image-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^gnumach-image-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^.*-modules-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^.*-modules-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^.*-modules-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^.*-kernel-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^.*-kernel-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^.*-kernel-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^linux-backports-modules-.*-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^linux-backports-modules-.*-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^linux-backports-modules-.*-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
   "^linux-tools-4\.4\.0-38-generic$";
   "^linux-tools-4\.4\.0-42-generic$";
   "^linux-tools-4\.4\.0-43-generic$";
};
/* Debug information:
# dpkg list:
rc  linux-image-3.11.0-17-generic               3.11.0-17.31                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic               3.11.0-18.32                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.11.0-19-generic               3.11.0-19.33                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic               3.13.0-24.47                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic               3.13.0-27.50                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-29-generic               3.13.0-29.53                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic               3.13.0-30.55                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic               3.13.0-32.57                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic               3.13.0-33.58                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic               3.13.0-34.60                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic               3.13.0-35.62                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic               3.13.0-36.63                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic               3.13.0-39.66                                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic               3.16.0-25.33~14.04.2                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-28-generic               3.16.0-28.38~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-29-generic               3.16.0-29.39~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic               3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-33-generic               3.16.0-33.44~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic               3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic               3.16.0-36.48~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-37-generic               3.16.0-37.51~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-38-generic               3.16.0-38.52~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-39-generic               3.16.0-39.53~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.16.0-40-generic               3.16.0-40.54~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-21-generic               3.19.0-21.21~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-22-generic               3.19.0-22.22~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-23-generic               3.19.0-23.24~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-25-generic               3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-26-generic               3.19.0-26.28~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-28-generic               3.19.0-28.30~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-30-generic               3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-31-generic               3.19.0-31.36~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-32-generic               3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.19.0-33-generic               3.19.0-33.38~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-18-generic                4.2.0-18.22~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-19-generic                4.2.0-19.23~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-21-generic                4.2.0-21.25~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-22-generic                4.2.0-22.27~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-23-generic                4.2.0-23.28~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-25-generic                4.2.0-25.30~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-27-generic                4.2.0-27.32~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-30-generic                4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-32-generic                4.2.0-32.37~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.2.0-34-generic                4.2.0-34.39~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-10-generic                4.4.0-10.25                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-11-generic                4.4.0-11.26                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-12-generic                4.4.0-12.28                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-13-generic                4.4.0-13.29~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-14-generic                4.4.0-14.30~14.04.2                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-15-generic                4.4.0-15.31~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-18-generic                4.4.0-18.34~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic                4.4.0-21.37                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic                4.4.0-22.40                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-24-generic                4.4.0-24.43                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic                4.4.0-28.47                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic                4.4.0-31.50                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic                4.4.0-34.53                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic                4.4.0-36.55                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic                4.4.0-38.57                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic                4.4.0-42.62                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic                4.4.0-43.63                                                 amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.11.0-17-generic         3.11.0-17.31                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.11.0-18-generic         3.11.0-18.32                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.11.0-19-generic         3.11.0-19.33                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic         3.13.0-24.47                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic         3.13.0-27.50                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-29-generic         3.13.0-29.53                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic         3.13.0-30.55                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic         3.13.0-32.57                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-33-generic         3.13.0-33.58                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic         3.13.0-34.60                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic         3.13.0-35.62                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic         3.13.0-36.63                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic         3.13.0-39.66                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic         3.13.0-40.69                                                amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-25-generic         3.16.0-25.33~14.04.2                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-28-generic         3.16.0-28.38~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-29-generic         3.16.0-29.39~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic         3.16.0-30.40~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic         3.16.0-33.44~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic         3.16.0-34.47~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-36-generic         3.16.0-36.48~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-37-generic         3.16.0-37.51~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-38-generic         3.16.0-38.52~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-39-generic         3.16.0-39.53~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-40-generic         3.16.0-40.54~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-21-generic         3.19.0-21.21~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-22-generic         3.19.0-22.22~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-23-generic         3.19.0-23.24~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-25-generic         3.19.0-25.26~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-26-generic         3.19.0-26.28~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-28-generic         3.19.0-28.30~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-30-generic         3.19.0-30.34~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-31-generic         3.19.0-31.36~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-32-generic         3.19.0-32.37~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.19.0-33-generic         3.19.0-33.38~14.04.1                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-18-generic          4.2.0-18.22~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-19-generic          4.2.0-19.23~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-21-generic          4.2.0-21.25~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-22-generic          4.2.0-22.27~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-23-generic          4.2.0-23.28~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-25-generic          4.2.0-25.30~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-27-generic          4.2.0-27.32~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-30-generic          4.2.0-30.36~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-32-generic          4.2.0-32.37~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.2.0-34-generic          4.2.0-34.39~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-10-generic          4.4.0-10.25                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-11-generic          4.4.0-11.26                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-12-generic          4.4.0-12.28                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-13-generic          4.4.0-13.29~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-14-generic          4.4.0-14.30~14.04.2                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-15-generic          4.4.0-15.31~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-18-generic          4.4.0-18.34~14.04.1                                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic          4.4.0-21.37                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic          4.4.0-22.40                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-24-generic          4.4.0-24.43                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic          4.4.0-28.47                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic          4.4.0-31.50                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic          4.4.0-34.53                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic          4.4.0-36.55                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rH  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-38-generic          4.4.0-38.57                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-generic          4.4.0-42.62                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-generic          4.4.0-43.63                                                 amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                         4.4.0.43.45                                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
# list of installed kernel packages:
4.4.0-38-generic 4.4.0-38.57
4.4.0-42-generic 4.4.0-42.62
4.4.0-43-generic 4.4.0-43.63
# list of different kernel versions:
4.4.0-43.63
4.4.0-42.62
4.4.0-38.57
# Installing kernel: 4.4.0-38.57 (4.4.0-38-generic)
# Running kernel: 4.4.0-43.63 (4.4.0-43-generic)
# Last kernel: 4.4.0-43.63
# Previous kernel: 4.4.0-42.62
# Kernel versions list to keep:
4.4.0-38.57
4.4.0-42.62
4.4.0-43.63
# Kernel packages (version part) to protect:
4\.4\.0-38-generic
4\.4\.0-42-generic
4\.4\.0-43-generic
*/

pilot6@Pilot6:~$ aptitude search '^linux* ?installed'
i A linux-base                      - Linux image base package                  
i   linux-firmware                  - Firmware for Linux kernel drivers         
i   linux-generic                   - Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers 
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-34          - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic  - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-36          - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic  - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-38          - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic  - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-42          - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-42-generic  - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-43          - Header files related to Linux kernel versi
i A linux-headers-4.4.0-43-generic  - Linux kernel headers for version 4.4.0 on 
i A linux-headers-generic           - Generic Linux kernel headers              
i A linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic    - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64
i A linux-image-4.4.0-43-generic    - Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64
i A linux-image-extra-4.4.0-42-gene - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4
i A linux-image-extra-4.4.0-43-gene - Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4
i A linux-image-generic             - Generic Linux kernel image                
i   linux-libc-dev                  - Linux Kernel Headers for development      
i   linux-sound-base                - base package for ALSA and OSS sound system

pilot6@Pilot6:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

After the previous run of `apt autoremove` all `linux-image` packages have been removed except 4.4.0-42 and 43, but the headers are kept.

This is the debug-autoremove.txt from the affected installation.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89297281/debug-autoremove.txt

This is the output from the same command from a non-affected machine.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89297281/debug-autoremove-good.txt

Here is the first one with sudo.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23343952/

Comment: +1 Would be interested in answers too, for me it removes only the linux-extra package, and not even the main image... For now I've just resorted to removing them manually since it's just two packages.

Comment: Do you have a test case? If so, could you post the contents of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels` and the output of `aptitude search '^linux* ?installed'` . Just to confirm that all kernels are auto installed.

Comment: @user.dz I added the information.

Comment: @Pilot6, Could you generate debug from both machines (w/ & w/out problem) using `apt-get -o Debug::pkgAutoRemove=1 -s autoremove 2> debug-autoremove.txt` (no need for `sudo`, it's a simulation `-s`).  I got a test case for old headers, but I don't have multiple installations to compare.  I expect, it's a dependency  problem with virtual package (virtualbox 5 in my case) `Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic:amd64 4.4.0-36.55` which it's only difference I could find comparing to `linux-image`.

Comment: @user.dz I added the debug info from both machines.

Comment: I did not find anything useful in the output, but you gave me the correct tip. I removed `virtualbox-5.0` and then `apt autoremove`. All all headers has been removed. But it is really weird.

Comment: It seems that you ran it after removing virtualbox, could you run the command again after reinstalling virtualbox as it was before? Also use root account or sudo `apt-get -o Debug::pkgAutoRemove=1 -s autoremove 2> debug-autoremove.txt` because your output looks different then mine, No `Marking: linux-headers-...`, I will upload mine to let you compare it too.

Comment: Here is mine (filtered with `grep -e "linux-image" -e "linux-header" -e "virtualbox"` to make it small and fit to pastebin site)  https://paste.ubuntu.com/23343761/

Comment: The first one was before removing VB 5.0, the second comp never had VB. I posted the one with sudo. But I installed VB 5.1. now. I guess this is the solution. Anyway the problem was in VB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`autoremove` will remove any package that:

- is auto installed
- is not included in `APT::NeverAutoRemove` APT configuration
- don't have any dependents

Here is the debuging steps we followed

1. Checked auto/manual installation

   ```
   aptitude search '^linux* ?installed'
   ```
2. Checked currently declared versions under `APT::NeverAutoRemove`

   ```
   cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels
   ```
3. Checked dependency

   ```
   apt-cache rdepends linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic
   ```

   brings nothing but

   ```
   sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgAutoRemove=1 -s autoremove 2> debug-autoremove.txt

   ...
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-43-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-43.63
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-43-generic:amd64 4.4.0-43.63
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-42-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-42.62
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-42-generic:amd64 4.4.0-42.62
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-38-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-38.57
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic:amd64 4.4.0-38.57
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-36-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-36.55
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic:amd64 4.4.0-36.55
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-34-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-34.53
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic:amd64 4.4.0-34.53
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-31-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-31.50
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic:amd64 4.4.0-31.50
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-28-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-28.47
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic:amd64 4.4.0-28.47
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-24-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-24.43
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-24-generic:amd64 4.4.0-24.43
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-22-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-22.40
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 4.4.0-22.40
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-21-lowlatency:amd64 4.4.0-21.37
   Following dep: virtualbox-5.0:amd64 5.0.20-106931~Ubuntu~wily Recommends linux-headers:amd64 , provided by linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic:amd64 4.4.0-21.37
   ...
   ```

   So it's a dependency issue through the virtual package `linux-headers`

I'm in doubt here, It seems to me as bug.

- Either in autoremove function, it can't deal with virtual package dependency.
- Or in virtualbox package, that may need another way to declare dependency to Linux headers.

Answer (score 1):

I generally do not trust much in automatically running system maintenance actions when it comes to important topics  like kernel management. As I can see from your comments, there seems to be an interference with VirtualBox 5. So I recommend the most reliable way to clean up old kernels.

Check which kernel versions are installed : `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux`

To check especially for headers : `dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-headers`

Remove the ones you want to get rid of (replace * with the kernel version number) :

```
sudo apt purge linux-headers-* linux-headers-*-generic linux-image-*-generic linux-image-extra-*-generic linux-signed-image-*-generic
```

This is of course not an explanation what went wrong and why the automatic headers removal does not work when running the `apt autoremove` command, but in the end it is a solution to achieve what you want and it additionally makes sure that everything is cleaned up properly.

Comment: This is what I am doing now ;-) The question is what was the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: @Pilot6 : You said that VirtualBox is the root cause, so when they cannot fix it in one of the next versions, you can consider switching to KVM (qemu / virt-manager). That is what I did some time ago ... not a single problem since and the performance is great ! :)